Why doesn't std::begin have a noexcept specifier?
Why are std::begin and std::end defined without noexcept specifier, but std::cbegin is defined with it?
From the Standard:
// 23.7 C5 (14882:2020)
template<class C>
constexpr auto cbegin(const C& c) noexcept(noexcept(std::begin(c)))
    -> decltype(std::begin(c));

Following the same scheme, std::begin could be defined as:
template<class C>
constexpr auto begin(C& c) noexcept(noexcept(c.begin()))
    -> decltype(c.begin());

What's the trick?

I allowed myself to change the tag (from C++20 to C++17) since std::begin did not change with C++20 (Actually C++20 added std::ranges::begin to replace it).

Don't know the specific reasoning to be conservative here, but it usually goes back to "The Lakos Rule". And it's still being discussed to this day https://wg21.link/p3155

Even more detailed info from Lakos himself: https://wg21.link/P2861
